# Checkbox selection model is not showing row is check checked

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a grid with `selType: 'checkboxmodel'`. I selecting few record and send their details to server. Now when I reload the store I wanted those record to be selected. so I am writing this code.

Note : SelectedID record is an array with id of the record

```
if(this.SelectedID.length > 0){

    for(var i=0; i<SelectedID.length; i++){
        this.getSelectionModel().select(thistore.getById(SelectedID[i]),true);
    }
}
```

Now in this case it is fiering the `select` event but not checkbox is not getting ticked. But Surprisingly this is working fine in fiddler. [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/271v)

Any help will be thankfull.

Comment: what you mean by 'thistore.getById'. Is it a spelling mistake?

Comment: That is my `grid` store.

Comment: If you could, please post your html portion too.

Comment: I updated same code in fiddler but there it is working fine

Comment: Can anyone explain why downvote ?